# google.maps.setCenter() latitude & Longitude requested via jquery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, google-maps, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've got an jquery autocomplete ui element that shows a list of rail stations. When a user selects a Station from the autocomplete list,  the function should return a set of latitude/Coordinates from the db  and recenter the map over those cordinates?

Anyone spot where i'm code wrong in this code?

```
// make a json request to get the map data from the Map action
$(function() {         
    $.getJSON("/Home/Map", initialise);
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "EMPTY"});




function initialise(mapData) {

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.466667, -3.233333);

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {

        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
    },
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false

};


var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map")[0],
myOptions);


   $.each(mapData, function (i, location) {
       setupLocationMarker(map, location);
   });

//Autocomplete 
 $(function () {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: "/Home/StationsList",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "Home/GetStationLatLong/" + ui.item.value,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        map.setCenter(new google.maps.latLng(data.latitude, data.longitude));
                    }                       
                });
            }
        });

    });

}

function setupLocationMarker(map, location) {

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title: location.Name

});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infowindow.setContent('<h2>' + location.Name + '</h2>');

    infowindow.open(map, marker);


    $("#info").text(location.Name);
});     

}
```

The JSON Returned from the server by the "Home/GetStationLatLong" request looks like this

```
[{"latitude":53.66314,"longitude":-1.48149}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(data[0].latitude, data[0].longitude));
```

Comment: Now marked you as the correct answer as i was asking for setCenter in the first place

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your looking for this

```
success: function (data){
  //map.setCenter(new google.maps.latLng(coordinates[0].latitude, data.longitude));
   var coordinates = $.parseJON(data);
   map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[0].latitude, coordinates[0].longitude));
}
```

Comment: Yes that's right i was. Didn't work at first, but by adding data[0].latitude, data[0].longitude as per bsrykt says below made it work correctly

Comment: Actually i prefer setCenter for my use case, so i've marked bsrykt as the correct answer, but thanks for setting me on the right path. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The success function should be like:

```
success: function(data) {
    google.maps.setCenter(new google.maps.latLng(data.latitude, data.longitude));
}
```